# Just activated Firebase Cloud Messaging, what are all "credentials" entries?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

As mentioned, just enabled FCM API.

On that page, there's a "credentials" dropdown. It has eleven entries! What on earth are those? One is called "Anonymous", one "Unspecified". Two entries are "firebase-sdk".

Nowhere does it explain what all those credentials are and I have not found any documentation related to this. How do I know which ones are needed, and which ones I can safely remove?

To me, it doesn't inspire confidence in the security of FCM.

Anyone knows of this and/or any documentation related to it?

Cheers